# How to optimize GULP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

A simple gulpfile was written that collects statics in a separate folder and the functionality for viewing changes is configured.
But there is a problem when changing the script starts to collect all the files in a row. it takes a lot of time, I want to configure so that when changing, everything is not collected in a row, but only those files that have been changed.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const less = require("gulp-less")
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const changed = require('gulp-changed');

const paths = {
   style: {
      src: 'static/**/*.less',
      dest: 'static/dist',
   }
}

function styles(){
 return gulp.src([paths.style.src, '!static/js/**' ])
 .pipe(less())
 .pipe(cleanCSS())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.dest))
 .pipe(gulp.src('static/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/images'))
 .pipe(gulp.src('static/my/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')) 
 .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/my/images'))
}

function buildLess() {
   return gulp.src(paths.style.src)
   .pipe(changed(paths.style.dest, { hasChanged: changed.compareContents }))
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(cleanCSS())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.dest))

}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.style.src, buildLess)
}

exports.styles = styles
exports.watch = watch
```

Comment: But that's how _watch_ works. Checks modify dates of _each_ file and then acts on modified files. Can you elaborate on _it takes a lot of time_? Lot of time to do what?

Comment: We have this `read: false`. I think it disables content check, just by file timestamps. `gulp.watch(sources.less.path, {read: false, interval: watchInterval}, parallel('build-less'))`. Just can't find documentation for that right now